# C # using System.Data.OleDb problem

Tags: c#, oledb, sharpdevelop

I have tried this on IDE **SharpDevelop** not on visual studio.
I am using the namespace like this:

```
using System.Data.OleDb;
```

But it is showing me following error:

```
'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'System'(are you missing an assembly reference?)(CS0234)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listen to the compiler: you're probably missing a reference to the `System.Data` assembly in your project. You need to add that reference using the `Add Reference...` dialog from the `Project` menu.

Comment: Thanks. I have added **System.Data** reference and error is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Add Reference then search `System.Data` and add to your program using

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Oledb;
```